# Admin page gives 404 error after domain name change

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, 404-page, domain

I have moved a magento store from one server to another and had the domain name changed as well. The front end works fine, the /admin/ just shows the magento 404 page.  I have tried every solution I could find - none have worked.

- updating/verifying app/etc/local.xml
- scanning the databse dump for instances of old domain name [none]
- dumping /var/cache/* /var/session/*
- ran this little bit of SQL:

> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
> UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code=’admin’;
> UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name=’Default’;
> UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code=’admin’;
> UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code=’NOT LOGGED IN’;
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

- checked .htaccess
- server and magento logs, an error shows up in the magento log:

> 2016-02-26T19:46:43+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1
> passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of
> Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in
> /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 645 and
> defined  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php on
> line 453
>
> 2016-02-26T19:46:43+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error:
> Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::setWebsite() must be
> an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in
> /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 665 and
> defined  in
> /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store/Group.php on line
> 275

Which leads to this:

```
public function setWebsite(Mage_Core_Model_Website $website)
    {
        $this->_website = $website;
    }
```

So something is calling the function but not passing in the $website variable.

How do I fix this??

Comment: Before you assume the lines in your log file are from your incorrect requests, which Magento 404 page are you seeing?  http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages

Comment: Just a guess... are you sure you are not redirected to the old domain?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check your database in `core_config_data` table settings.  Make sure that BOTH entries for your domain are set to the proper domain name.

The entries you must look for are:
`web/unsecure/base_url`
and
`web/secure/base_url`

Change both to be your new domain name.  Then clear the `var/session` and `var/cache` folders.

That should fix the problem.  If not, restart apache.  If that does not work, then make sure to clear whatever caching system you are using (redis, etc..)

**Note**: I'd highly recommend re-configuring to use something other than /admin for security reasons.